# No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: `INT64`, `ARRAY<INT64>`

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, syntax-error

I'm trying to generate a numeric series that has a interval of a numeric 30, representing 30 minutes respectively.

At the moment, my query is looking like this:

```
WITH bins AS(
    SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1470,30) AS low,
           GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1500,30) AS top
), ride AS(
    SELECT DATE_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,minute) as cicle
    FROM `data-project-389314.Cyclist.july23_trip_filtered`
    WHERE rideable_type != 'docked_bike'
)
SELECT low,
       top, 
       cicle
FROM      bins
LEFT JOIN ride
       ON cicle >= low  --Error line
      AND cicle < top
GROUP BY low,
         top
ORDER BY low
```

The error I keep on getting is:

> No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: `INT64`, `ARRAY<INT64>`. Supported signature: ANY >= ANY at [18:11]

I tried other codes which led me to recognize that Bigquery doesn't allow time date >= 24:00:00 but I kept getting error on that same variable always.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi - what is it that you don’t understand about that error message? You’re comparing a timestamp to an array which is a) not allowed and b) would be meaningless even if it was allowed. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What I tried to do is create a list where each row specify, beguining by the range, 00:00:00 to 01:00:00, and how many rides within this range has computed in the table.

I assume the problem is because 'cicle' isnt aggregated, like lemon stated.

I alredy updated my table because the colum I  have - ride_lenght- surpass the time range 24:00:00 and it was in a string format!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your query:

- Your `GENERATE_ARRAY` function will generate an array, not a table. Hence when you attempt to join on matching values, you're really attempting to match each single value of "*cicle*" with the full arrays.
- In the final query, you're using a `GROUP BY` clause, yet you're not using aggregate functions. You could use the `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate records, if that should feel necessary according to the nature of your data. Or if any aggregate function should be carried out, make sure to either aggregate "*cicle*" or add it to the `GROUP BY` clause, to avoid subtle errors.

In order to fix these errors, you can:

- change your first cte to unpack your arrays into tabular values, by cross-joining the application of `UNNEST` on the output of the `GENERATE_ARRAY` function
- adding the "*cicle*" column inside the `GROUP BY` clause, to reflect the cicle partition.

Minor optional fixes:

- using `BETWEEN ... AND ...` instead of two conditions inside the `WHERE` clause
- changing the name "top" to "high" (looks more suited with respect to "low")

```
WITH bins AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1470,30)) AS low,
         UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1500,30)) AS high
), ride AS(
    SELECT DATE_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,minute) as cicle
    FROM `data-project-389314.Cyclist.july23_trip_filtered`
    WHERE rideable_type != 'docked_bike'
)
SELECT DISTINCT low,
                high, 
                cicle  
FROM      bins
LEFT JOIN ride
       ON cicle BETWEEN low AND high
ORDER BY low
```

Comment: WITH bins AS(
     SELECT *
     FROM    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1470,30)) AS low,
             UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,1500,30)) AS high
), ride AS(
    SELECT count(rides_lenght) as cicle
    FROM `data-project-389314.Cyclist.july23_trip_filtered`
    WHERE rideable_type != 'docked_bike'
)

SELECT   low,
         high, 
         cicle  
FROM       bins
LEFT JOIN ride
       ON cicle BETWEEN low AND high
GROUP BY low,
         high
                 
ORDER BY low

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` is the correct way of writing `GROUP BY low, high` in the solution you modified here. You should use `GROUP BY` only in presence of [aggregate functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions).